# jQuery outerHeight() function with no arguments returning the object instead of parameter value

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

The function is printing the logs as-

```
console.log("top:"+$(token_list).outerHeight());
```

I am expecting the parameter value to be returned, so that I can add the css height like:

```
dropdown
   .css({
       position: "absolute",
       top: $(token_list).offset().top + $(token_list).outerHeight(),
       left: $(token_list).offset().left,
       'z-index': 999
     })
```

But its not taking the value of top as style because the method is returning object type value. 
Any suggestions how to fix this?

Comment: Please add makrup as well for dropdown

Comment: this is may be caused by an older version of jQuery UI. upgrade your jQuery Ui version and check

Answer (score 2):

What version of JQuery are you using?

Looks like a bug with JQuery Ui version 1.8.1 (see [here](https://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/12491) for bug info).

Include the `includeMargins` parameter and specify `false` to get the outer height of the element or update JQuery Ui.

```
dropdown
   .css({
       position: "absolute",
       top: $(token_list).offset().top + $(token_list).outerHeight(false),
       left: $(token_list).offset().left,
       'z-index': 999
     })
```